# Xamarin.Forms receiving an image from an api endpoint

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to pull an image from an api endpoint. So far everything works an appears except the image. I am not sure if its because I am calling it as a string or if i should change it to something else.

Below is my code, if more is needed or if im missing something please let me know.

Thank you

EventsDAL.cs

```
public class Events
    {
        public string EventTitle { get; set; }
        public string EventDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDateAndTime { get; set; }
        public string EventPosterImageURL { get; set; }
        public string EventTitleReturn { get { return EventTitle; } }
        public string EventDescriptionReturn { get { return EventDescription; } }
        public DateTime EventDateReturn { get { return EventDateAndTime; } }
        public string EventImageReturn { get { return EventPosterImageURL; } }

    }
```

EventsPage.xaml

```
<ScrollView >
            <ListView x:Name="lvEvent" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" >
                                <Label x:Name="lbTitle" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="{Binding EventTitleReturn}" FontSize="Title"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding EventDescriptionReturn}"  FontSize="Large"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding EventDateReturn}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding EventImageReturn}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
```

My controller

```
 public ActionResult Events()
        {
            var umbEvents = Umbraco.Content(1056).Children<Event>().ToList();
            var vmEvents = new List<EventViewModel>();
            foreach (var item in umbEvents)
                vmEvents.Add(new EventViewModel
                {
                    EventTitle = item.EventTitle,
                    EventDescription = item.EventShortDescription,
                    EventDateAndTime = item.EventDateAndTime,
                    EventPosterImageURL = item.EventPosterImage == null ? "" : item.EventPosterImage.Url,
                    EventURL = item.Url
                });
            return Json(vmEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Postman

"EventTitle": "Seeing Red!",

"EventDescription": "The Ladies of Seeing Red are one of the best acoustic bands on the Memphis music scene.  They provide a great variety of music for any environment.  It is a fun show with a great energy level and they adapt well to any size venue. Sponsored by ProBuilt of Memphis.",

"EventDateAndTime": "/Date(1599332400000)/",

"EventURL": "/events/seeing-red/",

"EventPosterImageURL": "/media/3ablnzez/seeingred.jpg"

Comment: space between binding '{ Binding' ? and can we actually see the image path? you can replace xxx.png with any sensitive data you do not want to post on stackoverflow

Comment: @LeRoy I have updated it with what i get from postman as well as what my controller looks like to pull this information. Hope this is enough info.

Comment: @Jason are you talking about in my controller? sorry, a little new to this aspect of it.

Comment: `"EventPosterImageURL": "/media/3ablnzez/seeingred.jpg"`- that is a path, not a url.  If you want the image to load from the remote server, you need to return a complete url - ie, `http://myserver.com/media/3ablnzez/seeingred.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"EventPosterImageURL": "/media/3ablnzez/seeingred.jpg"`

this is a path, not a url. If you want the image to load from the remote server, you need to return a complete url - ie, `http://myserver.com/media/3ablnzez/seeingred.jpg`